# In JMeter, how can I correlate/parameterize from HTTP Header Manager?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

My HTTP Request has child HTTP Header Manager. The HTTP Header Manager has dynamic values, and other parameters depending on search on GUI application. See picture. The **xsrf-token** is dynamic, and **auditlog** varies depending on my search by **vEnl**. I am using JMeter 4.0. The HTTP Requests are GET, and therefore cannot use the checkbox "Use multipart/form-data for POST" either. How can I correlate/parameterize in this situation?

[image: HTTP Header Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regular Expression Extractor` in the response of whatever request which has the right value for this `Header Manager`. Name it for example :`testDynaVar`

Then use `${testDynaVar}` in `auditlog`'s value. The parameter value will be passed to this header manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract this `xsrf-token` from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and substitute recorded hard-coded value with this variable in the HTTP Header Manager, check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/) article for example implementation.

HTTP Header Manager can evaluate JMeter Variables in the runtime and substitute the placeholders with the respective values:

[image]

[image]

with regards to this `auditlog` header your question doesn't contain enough information to come up with the proper configuration, from the first glance you can parameterize this `ctime` argument using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)